# Что означает 100% в @keyframes?

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, keyframes

Вопрос такой: что значит,если в `@keyframes` указываются только 100%(эквивалентно to) или только 0%
(эквивалентно from).

Например:

```
@keyframes spin_1 {100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }}

@keyframes spin_2 {0% { transform: rotate(360deg); }}
```

```css
.block_3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  animation: block 3s infinite linear;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
}

@keyframes block {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block_3"></div>
```

Comment: Без разницы, просто когда указываются проценты, можно внедрить промежуточные состояния.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> можно сказать, что если в animation-duration указано значение 3s, то
> при употреблении ТОЛЬКО 100%(или from), анимация начнется через целых
> три секунды. Однако, этого не происходит (см. пример в вопросе)

100% обозначает финиш анимации, то есть `to`,
`from` это 0% - старт анимации

Ваш пример можно было бы написать в подробной форме и она будет аналогична вашей сокращенной записи:

```css
.block_3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  animation: block 3s infinite linear;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
     transform: rotate(0deg);}

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block_3"></div>
```

Отложить начало анимации можно командой `animation-delay:3s;`

```css
.block_3 {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: pink;
      animation: block 3s infinite linear;
      animation-delay:3s;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 30px;
      transform-origin: 60px 60px;
    }

    @keyframes block {
      0% {
         transform: rotate(0deg);}

      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="block_3"></div>
```

Или можно добавить задержку в сокращенную форму записи

animation: block 3s infinite **3s** linear;

```css
.block_3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  animation: block 3s infinite 3s linear;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
     transform: rotate(0deg);}

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block_3"></div>
```

Comment: @Eva Здравствуйте! Недавно у вас был хороший вопрос, чем отличается `translate(100,100)` от viewBox="100 100 400 400"  Я видел этот вопрос, в голове уже созрел ответ,  но не успел, так как вы его, похоже удалили. Уже разобрались самостоятельно или всё же восстановите тот вопрос?

Comment: Здравствуйте, вопрос удалила т.к. разобралась сама, а толкового ответа на мой взгляд не было. Но не переживайте, вопросы по svg еще будут:)))

Comment: @Eva Это очень хорошо, что сами разобрались, лучше и на дольше запомнится Главное правило для viewBox - у него все наоборот: положительная координата `X` сдвигает влево. Увеличение viewBox - уменьшает картинку.

Answer (score 3):

0% - начало, то есть, с этого должна начинаться анимация.

100% - конец, то есть, к такому кадру должен прийти элемент к концу анимации.

Также вы можете указывать промежуточные состояния. Всё это также делается с помощью процентов.

Например: вам надо чтобы к середине анимации поменялся цвет текста на красный, тогда вместо 100% вы пишите 50% и говорите `{color:red;}` и цвет должен плавно поменяться на нужный

Comment: да, все верно. Но исходя из этого, можно сказать, что если в animation-duration указано значение 3s, то при употреблении ТОЛЬКО 100%(или from), анимация начнется через целых три секунды. Однако, этого не происходит (см. пример в вопросе)